# Errors in writing a toast in android studio (java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, toast

I am a very beginner at AndroidStudio. I opened a new empty project in java language and I just want to show a toast but every time it is showing many errors.
LIKE:

1. **Cannot resolve method 'makeText(com.example.newapp.MainActivity, java.lang.String, int)'**
2. **Cannot resolve method 'getActivity' in 'MainActivity'**
3. **Cannot resolve method 'getApplicationContext' in 'MainActivity' ETC.**

I looked on the internet and tried every method to make a toast in android studio but every time I get errors. I've tried 5 methods but I don't understand why I am getting errors.

[image: pic]

**Here is the code:**

```
package com.example.newapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void startApp(View view)
    {
        Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(this, "message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "message",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast toast3 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"message",Toast. LENGTH_SHORT);
        Toast toast4 = Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"message",Toast. LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace getActivity() with **this** in your code.

Answer (score 0):

first of all your code looks ok, but some notes :

1. first, you create a method but you don't call it anywhere in the
   Activity lifecycle method.
2. Next, when you are in an Activity class that is one of the child of  Context class , you don't need to use getActivity(), or any other methods , you can simply pass `this` or `YourActivityClassName.this`.
3. The last thing is that why you have view parameter in method signature when you don't need it?
4. Delete unused method parameters from method, then replace getActivity() with this or MainActivity.this, at the last call your method in `onCreate` method by writing your methodName with double parentheses.

Edit:

5. Don't forget to call the `show()` method on your Toast yo show it ;)